# I have not received tumbleweed badge although it seems I should have

Tags: support, badges, tumbleweed-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122525/windows-wmi-get-a-snapshot-enabledstate) question on Stack Overflow more then a week ago (on 29th of October). It has 12 views, no votes till yesterday and still no answer. As I understand I should have received a tumbleweed badge on this question but I haven't. Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tumbleweed badge is awarded once as mentioned in [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/166025)
 post. You already received it on [May 10](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/63/tumbleweed).

Comment: Yep, you can see all the details about all badges in [this faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Comment: Ahh I got it now. I didn't pay attention to this. Thank you.